# How to assign a MySQL statement to a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked all over the web and cannot seem to find a proper way to assign the result of a MySQL query to a PHP variable. The code that I currently have returns a "resource id #3" error. Here is what it looks like.

```
//Select the 'aQID' of the question that has it's BOOL set to "true"

$currentQ = mysql_query("SELECT aQID FROM approvedQuestions WHERE status='1'");

$cuQ = mysql_result($currentQ,1,"status");

echo $cuQ;
```

I know that the query will only ever return one record (the active question). But I cannot seem to figure out what function to use.

Comment: Are you sure you have looked all over the web and can't find the proper answer? This is one of the most principle thing if you are using PHP/MySQL. There are examples on PHP manuel, go and read them first: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$currentQ = mysql_query("SELECT aQID FROM approvedQuestions WHERE status='1'");

    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($currentQ);

    var_dump($rs);
```

Comment: so the variable I would use would be "$rs" ??

Comment: @Drake yes, and you can certainly change the variable's name.